# Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getConnection on object Jdbc

Tags: sql-server, google-apps-script, jdbc

I've used the same Google APP Script code to connect to my MS SQL server for the last year.

`var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://XXXXXXX:1433;databaseName=XXX","XXX","XXX");`

All my mobile apps, ODBC, server management studio all connect fine. I haven't made any code changes to my google app script but now I'm getting the error **Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getConnection on object Jdbc** when I run that line of the app script. Tested from multiple locations and computers.

GoDaddy confirmed there are no reasons Google APP Script should suddenly stop working. I've made no code changes, and it's stopped working from several different Google App Scripts.

Any ideas or debug advice to get a better error message? Could it have to do with the upgrade that happened to JDBC for SQL server 8/4 and it's just rolled out to the server I may be working from?

Comment: What is `Jdbc`?  Normally you use `DriverManager.GetConnection(url)`, see eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/working-with-a-connection?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that pops up with Google from time to time.
We are currently having the same issue with scripts that have worked for years.  The last time it happened Google fixed within 24 hours.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756432

Also whenever this happens there are usually lots of bug tickets that start showing up.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=jdbc

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what happened, it worked this morning without me doing anything!